# performing a child classes method when called as a parent

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, class, parent-child

I have a class Class A, and a class Class B.
class B is a child of class A so that:

```
public class Class A
{
   public DateTime FileStart
   {
      get
      {
          return Header.StartTime;
      }
      set{ }
   }
   ...
   ...
}
```

and

```
public class B : A
{
   FileInfo zippedA;
   public A myA = null;
   internal B(FileInfo mFileInfo)
   {
      ...
      //collects the same data as A from the fileinfo such as  start time...
      ...
   }
   public A getAData()
   {
      UnZipFile(zippedA);
      return myA;
   }
   ...
}
```

So I'm looking for a way to call `getAData()` whenever an object of `B` is called as `A` for example the list Xlist stores all As and Bs but will be accessed from several places in the code:

```
   SortedList Xlist = new SortedList();
   public void GetFrames(DateTime desiredStartTime, DateTime  desiredEndTime)
   {
       for(int fileIdx = Xlist.Values.Count-1; fileIdx >= 0; --fileIdx)
       {
           //my hope is that there is a way to set up B in it's class to say
           // "if I get called as an A, I'll perform getAData() and return myA instead.
           A rec = (A)Xlist.GetByIndex(fileIdx);
           ...
           ...
       }
   }
```

in the above instance I would like for every time an object is pulled from Xlist if its a B but gets caste as an A like so, it automatically calls the `getAData()` function and returns the resulting A instead of its self. is this possible??

Comment: Too hard to say from just this much info, but inheritance seems to be bad way to go. @evanmcdonnal's answer will get you out of jail for now. But I'd be looking at B has an A rather than is an A (Aggregation) or delegating unzip somehow. The further down your current road you go, the worse you design will get. A will end up with masses of do nothing virtual methods that you may or may not override in descendants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the method in parent class `virtual` and override it in the child classes. In doing so anywhere you call the method on an instance of type A, it will invoke the method in the derived type if the derived type provides and override, otherwise it will invoke the version in type A.

This is the simplest way, the alternative aren't very attractive. For more information on virtual methods in C# check out this msdn article; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645767(v=vs.71).aspx

To do what you think you want to do (I'm pretty sure it's not actually what you want to do) you can do this;

```
   for(int fileIdx = Xlist.Values.Count-1; fileIdx >= 0; --fileIdx)
   {
       A rec = (A)Xlist.GetByIndex(fileIdx);
       if (rec.GetType() == typeof(B))
       {
            B temp = (B) rec;
            rec = temp.getAData();
       }
   }
```

Although, again, this makes no sense at all. Here's an example;

```
public class Car
{
     int year;
     bool manual;
}

public class Porsche : Car
{
    bool specialPorscheOnlyFeature;
    Engine enginge;
}

public class Engine
{
   string engineType;
} 
// in some method

Porsche p = new Porsche();
// to get Car data
int yearOfCar = p.year; 
bool isManual = p.manual;
bool specialFeature = p.SpecialPorscheOnlyFeature;
```

Above is an example of how inheritance works. I don't retrieve an instance of the base class, everything the base class has is baked into the instance of the derived class. You're acting like the base class is some other object the derived class is composed of.

Comment: I don't think you understand the question, class A doesn't have the function I want to call, class B does. any time an object of Class B is called as an A i want it to automatically perform it's function and return it's internal instance of A

Comment: @DarthSheldon it seems like you're confused about how inheritance works. Why would type B inherit from type A and be composed of an instance of type A? That relationship just doesn't make sense. You understand that an instance of type B has all the properties/methods that an instance of type A has plus more, right? If you have for example `A[]` and it has objects of type `B` in it when you interact with those objects the calling code does not know that they're of type `B`, only the properties/methods on type `A` are exposed.

Comment: yeah that makes sense, maybe I've just explained this awful twice in a row (would not surprise me) but I want my object B to act like an A, the only issue is B contains a zipped file, while A contains an unzipped file. so A has access to the files information, B does not, in order for someone to access the data of the zipped file, it has to be recorded into the database in a similar fashion to an unziped file (hence B class) yet I need to be able to tell when a B is being called upon, rather then an A so I know I must 1.unzip the file, 2. make an A for the file, and 3. replace the B with new A

Comment: @DarthSheldon ok that's reasonable although not a good design. What you should do is make is so A has the unzipped file and B has the zipped file in addition to the unzipped file. B shouldn't change core properties of A, it is supposed to reuse them. If you do that, then when you're dealing with an list of type A references (these instances could actually be of type B) you can operate on them just like they were A's and only A's. If your design makes it so that is not possible then you should change your design.

Comment: here's the issue. this system holds 31 days worth of data at once, each hour 6 files are created and each file is aprox 30MB, thats 4k files each 30MB, needless to say if the system zipped a file then I don't get the original file unless I go unzip it specifically. SO each zip's name is 'filename_CreationTime/Date_LastAccessTime/Date.zip" that can be split up and put into the B's parameters(inherited from A), but I still need to access all the formatted data in the files.

Comment: A knows about that data, but in the case of a zipped file the data is just set to null until unzipped

Comment: @DarthSheldon alright, so add a zipped property to class `A`. In class `B`'s constructor set that to true, in class `A`'s set it to false. Then, you can tell whether or not the file is zipped while still only looking at fields exposed by class `A`.

Comment: my god... I've been blind!!! thats so freaking easy why did I never just add a 'isZipped' flag! thanks!

Comment: oops, thought I did. have now!

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best way to do it, but would this not work?

```
class File
{
    public string FileInfo = "";

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FileInfo;
    }

    public virtual File GetRaw()
    {
        return this;
    }
}

class ZippedFile : File
{
    public File Unzip()
    {
        // Do actual unzip here..
        return new File { FileInfo = FileInfo.Substring(0,8) };
    }

    public override File GetRaw()
    {
        return Unzip();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<object> files = new List<object>();

        files.Add(new File { FileInfo = "BeepBoop" });
        files.Add(new ZippedFile { FileInfo = "BeepBoopfQAWEFRLQER:LKAR:LWEasdfw;lekfrqW:ELR" });
        files.Add(new File { FileInfo = "BoopBeep" });
        files.Add(new ZippedFile { FileInfo = "BoopBeepAWSLF:KQWE:LRKsdf;lKWEFL:KQwefkla;sdfkqwe" });

        foreach(var f in files)
        {
            File rawFile = ((File)f).GetRaw();
            Console.WriteLine(rawFile);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```