# Why I am not able to call methods of child class from parent's reference variable

Tags: c#, oop, object, inheritance

Here I am able to call parent class method from the instance of child class and reference variable of parent class.

```
public class A
{
    public void showA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("showA");
    }
}
public class B:A
{
    public void showB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("showB");
    }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A obj = new B();
        obj.showA(); //why I am not able to call obj.showB()
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you got the opposite meaning of inheritance. The fact that B is A does not mean that A is B

Comment: Please take the [Tour].to see how SO is supposed to work with regards to answers you get.

Comment: `obj` is a reference to `A`. You can assign any instance of `A` to it, or any instance of any subclass of `A`. So it doesn't guarantee that the object it refers to will be of type `B` -- far from it. Therefore, it only lets you reference `A` members of the object it references *This is what the `A` in front of `A obj` means*. It means "I promise that this thing is an `A`, no more and no less". Maybe it's a `B`, maybe there's some other subclass of `A` called `C` -- could be any of the above. The type of the reference guarantees *only* that it's some kind of `A`.

Comment: To elaborate on @Ed's comment: what would you expect the code to do if you'd written something like this: `A obj = new C(); obj.showB();` where `C` is a class like `class C : A { public void showC() { ... } }`? That is, having assigned an instance of _`C`_ to `obj` you still try to write the code you want to write. How is the compiler supposed to tell the difference and protect you from yourself?

Comment: The marked duplicate explains your literal scenario. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023200/call-method-from-a-parent-class-and-use-child-class-properties and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414160/performing-a-child-classes-method-when-called-as-a-parent for other options. If you have a pattern of class members where you want the child-implemented method to be called always, I recommend the `virtual`/`override` option. See also "polymorphism".

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance a fundamental building block for C#.  The paradigm can be easier to understand in the form of polymorphism, especially with an interface.  In C# you're unable to inherit from more than one class, but can inherit multiple interfaces.

To understand the concept we will build the following:

```
public interface IColor
{
     void WriteColor();
}
```

The above doesn't implement any logic, it acts as a declaration of intent.  So, we will write our classes now.

```
public class Rectangle : IColor
{
     public void WriteColor() => Console.WriteLine("Red");
}

public class Circle : IColor
{
     public void WriteColor() => Console.WriteLine("Blue");
}
```

When you implement, when you create your rectangle or circle object, you can invoke the method `WriteColor`.  But, they're different though you have the same method name.  This is through polymorphism, your interface allows the logic to be separated.  So you have two completely separate implementations.

The other form though is through a class directly, which creates different terminology based on how you're inheriting.

```
// Object:
public class ShapeColor
{
     private string color;

     public Color(string color) => this.color = color;

     public string Color { get; } = color;
}
```

We will create a shape object, to expand the example:

```
// Shape: Object (Sub Class)
// ShapeColor: Base Object (Base Class)
public class Shape : ShapeColor 
{
     private string shape;   

     public Shape(string shape, string color) : base(color)
     {
          this.shape = shape;
     }

     public string TypeOfShape { get; } = shape;
}
```

So, if you call a shape object the base class in this case requires a color, so you would pass a shape and a color.  To expand this further, we will now create our next object.

```
public class BuildShape : Shape
{
     public void BuildRectangle()
     {
          var shape = new Shape("Rectangle", "Red");
          Console.WriteLine(shape.TypeOfShape);
          Console.WriteLine(shape.Color);
     }
}
```

So what the?  `BuildShape` could access our properties from shape and shape color, why?  Well, shape color is defined as a base class, meaning that our shape is dependent on the color.  The type of shape is exposed as we inherit from shape.  This is due to the following:

- Shape color, our base or super class of Shape.
- Shape the sub class of shape color, but the direct super class of build shape.

The above represents our order of inheritance. If you're confused, we can simplify by explaining:

- Base Class: the base keyword is used to access members of the base class from within a derived class
- Sub Class & Super Class: The optional extends clause in a class declaration specifies the direct superclass of the current class. A class is said to be a direct subclass of the class it extends. The direct superclass is the class from whose implementation the implementation of the current class is derived.

You can read more about the topic [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/inheritance).